# Setting up Fixer.io, Python

Tags: python, fixer.io

I am trying to use the fixer.io API but I can't understand how to submit my access key!

I have been trying with these code snippets: https://pypi.org/project/fixerio/

For example:

```
from fixerio import Fixerio

fxrio = Fixerio()
fxrio.latest()
```

but then I receive:

```
404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://api.fixer.io/latest
```

I have also tried the examples found here: http://fixerio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from fixerio import Fixerio

fxrio = Fixerio(access_key='513eb....')
fxrio.latest()
```

but there is no kwarg "access_key". The only kwarg's are base, symbols and secure.

Finally I have also tried editing my client.py(with no success) but I assume that is wrong.

I am using version 0.1.1

Thankful for any support!

Comment: Can you print fxrio? and post the output pls After fxrio=Fixerio(access_key='513eb....') 
print(fxrio)

Comment: No, when I run fxrio=Fixerio(access_key='513eb....') the program crashes and fxrio never gets initiated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the docs were up to date with the latest alpha-version, but through pip install I was only able to download their older version 0.1.1.

I solved it by manually updating it from GitHub.